# How can I print data in multi dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I'm using Python 2.7 and I have a list of data in this structure:

`list = [(('a', 'b'), 'foo', (1, 2)), (('c', 'd'), 'bar', (3, 4)), (('e', 'f'), 'baz', (5, 6))]`

how can I print such that I get this output:

`(a, b)
(c, d)
(e, f)`

I've tried printing it like this `print list[0:][0])` but this returns `((a, b), 'foo', (1, 2))`

then I've tried printing it like this `print list[0:][0][0])` but this didn't work as it only returns `(a, b)` and none of the rest

I'm looking for a short efficient solution as I will use this tuple in conditions for checking if they already exist in the list

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean the list to be defined as: `[((a, b), 'foo', (1, 2)), ((c, d), 'bar', (3, 4)),((e, f), 'baz', (5, 6))]`? Otherwise, it might be very difficult to do what you want. Where the last element is `((e, f), 'baz', (5, 6))`.

Comment: @busybear yes it was a missing bracket, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your list looks like (replacing the undefined symbols with strings):

```
In [135]: alist = [(('a', 'b'), 'foo', (1, 2)), (('c', 'd'), 'bar', (3, 4)), (('e', 'f', 'baz', (5, 6)))]
```

The normal list display

```
In [136]: alist
Out[136]: 
[(('a', 'b'), 'foo', (1, 2)),
 (('c', 'd'), 'bar', (3, 4)),
 ('e', 'f', 'baz', (5, 6))]
```

I can iterate through the list and collect the first element of each tuple:

```
In [137]: [x[0] for x in alist]
Out[137]: [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), 'e']
```

Close, except the last tuple is different. Is that intentional, or did you just miss a pair of ()?

I could define a little function that formats a string for tuple without ().  It can also distinguish between the 3 element tuples and the 4.

```
def pfoo1(atuple):
    if len(atuple)==3:
        return '(%s, %s)'%atuple[0]
    else:
        return '(%s, %s)'%(atuple[:2])

In [159]: for x in alist:
     ...:     print(pfoo1(x))
     ...:     
(a, b)
(c, d)
(e, f)
In [161]: [pfoo1(x) for x in alist]
Out[161]: ['(a, b)', '(c, d)', '(e, f)']
In [162]: print('\n'.join(_))
(a, b)
(c, d)
(e, f)
```

So basically it's just a matter of iterating on the list, extracting the right elements from each tuple, and formatting them into a display string.

Comment: yes that was a  missing bracket, thanks for the notice!

Comment: Thanks you so much! you first solution worked as I intended!